# How to monitor socket without read data?

Tags: c, sockets

I have developed a C program that create a socket and check if we receive traffic on specified Linux interface:

program called like this:

```
sh # ./myprogram -t 10 -i eth0
```

My program look like this:

```
...
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int s, rv;
    int opt;
    struct timeval timeout;
    fd_set fd;
    t_config c;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "i:t:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 'i':
                if(optarg == NULL) {
                    usage(argv[0]);
                    return 1;
                }
                c.ifname = strdup(optarg);
                break;
            case 't':
                if(optarg == NULL) {
                    usage(argv[0]);
                    return 1;
                }
                timeout.tv_sec = atol(optarg);
                timeout.tv_usec = 0;
                printf("timeout %ld optarg=%s\n", timeout.tv_sec, optarg);
                break;
            case 'h':
            default:
                usage(argv[0]);
                return 1;
        }
    }
    s = CreateSocket(&c); // configure, create, bind socket
    FD_ZERO(&fd);
    FD_SET(s,&fd);
    while(1)
    {       
        rv = select(s+1, &fd, NULL, NULL, &timeout);        
        if(result == -1)
            printf("Error occured, err = %s",strerror(errno));
        else if(rv == 0)
        {
            printf("No frame received within %ld", timeout.tv_sec);
            somefunction();
        }
        else {/* there was data to read */}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program cannot detect traffic, despite I send traffic to pc my interface.

Comment: Is CreateSocket a home-made function ?

Comment: Can you share further information on the type of packets sent, logs obtained & remaining code.

Answer (score 0):

According the comment After `CreateSocket`, `bind` is not enough, you should `listen(2)` on it too.

Addtionally, as the `select(2)` says,

> Timeout is not changed by select(), and may be reused on subsequent
>   calls, however it is good style to re-initialize it before each
>   invocation of select().

In the BUGS section:

> In general it is unwise to assume that the timeout value will be
>   unmodified by the `select()` call, and the caller should reinitialize
>   it on each invocation.